# Show that there is no pair s.t. $a^1+a^2+a^3+...+a^n=b^m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,m$ and $n$ belong to integer. Is there any pair exist such that

$a^1+a^2+a^3+...+a^n=b^m$ where $a,b,m,n\ge 2$

Source code Pari/GP

```
for(m=2,10,for(n=2,10,for(a=2,100,for(b=2,100,if(sum(i=1,n,a^i)==b^m,print([a,n,b,m]))))))
```

Edit: more on observation

There always have at least one solution for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^i=b^m+k$ for every integer $k\ne 0$

---

*Apologies for the short question and shows no effort towards solution. Thank you*.

Comment: Your effort could be of the form : found no solutions till $a=...$ and $b = ...$, or you could mention what is the source of this problem (even if it is yours, where did you draw inspiration from and what techniques do you expect?)

Comment: There has been a lot of work on $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^n=b^m$, but this question is a little different. Still, some of the methods may apply.

Comment: The closed form would possibly help $a^1+a^2+\cdots+a^n=a\cdot{a^n-1\over a-1}$

Comment: You can simplify the problem to $a(a^{n}-1)/(a-1)=b^m$, but it's not clear to me how one would proceed from here.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks, it's my observation, usually I'm just play with number and trying to find new pattern and yes it takes efforts. I expect elementary solution :)

Comment: @Pruthviraj I did some basic checking. All I've come up so far is $a$ must be an integer to the $m$'th power (since $a$ and $1 + a + \ldots + a^{n-1}$ are coprime), which leads to the requirement $n \gt m$ (from $1 + a + \ldots + a^{n-1}$ also being an integer to the $m$'th power, say $d^m$, where if $a = c^m$, then $d \gt c^{n-1}$, so expanding $(c^{n-1} + 1)^{m}$ using the binomial theorem & doing some basic number bounds checking gets you $n \gt m$). You can use this to significantly reduce how many cases your script needs to check.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I believe I have a solution along your lines. Can you help me check my work?

Comment: Instead of apologizing, you could show some effort.

Answer (score 3):

Your identity can be expressed as $$a\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=b^m\,.$$
Observing that $\gcd(a, \frac{a^n-1}{a-1})=1$, this reduces to $$\frac{x^{mn}-1}{x^m-1}=y^m$$ assuming $a=x^m$ and $b=xy$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$.
Now, when $n=2$, we obtain $$y^m-x^m=1\,,$$ which cannot have any solution for nonzero $x,y$. Thus $n\ge 3$; this essentially becomes part of the equation $$\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=y^m$$ with $n\ge 3, |a|\ge 2,|y|\ge 2,m\ge 2$ that was investigated by Nagell and Ljunggren in the first half of the last century, which is conjectured to have the only known solutions $$ (a^n,y^m)\in\left\lbrace (3^5,11^2), (7^4,20^2),(18^3,7^3),((-19)^3,7^3)\right\rbrace\,,$$ none of which has the values of $a\in\{3,7,18,-19\}$ being an $m$th power. So your problem has no solutions conditional on the Nagell-Ljunggren conjecture. In fact, thanks to the $abc$-conjecture (if Mochizuki’s proof is\has been confirmed by experts), then Shorey (1986) showed that there are only **finitely** many solutions. (It may well be that your problem is *easier* to solve in general because the $a$ variable is an $m$th power; however, I have not considered this possibility carefully in its own right).

Answer (score 1):

(This is incomplete)

$$a ( 1+ a^2 + \ldots a^{n-1}) = b^m$$

Since $ \gcd(a, 1+ a^2 + \ldots a^{n-1}) = 1$, both of these terms must be powers of $m$. Let $ a = c^m$ and $b = cd$, which gives us

$$ d^ m = \frac{ c^{mn} -1 } { c^m - 1}  > \frac{ c^{mn}}{c^m}   \Rightarrow d > c^{n-1}. $$

If $ n < m$, then $ (c^{n-1} +1)^m (c^m-1) > c^{mn} -1 \Rightarrow  c^{n-1} + 1 > d$. Hence, there are no integer solutions for $d$.

So we must have $ n \geq m$.

Comment: Can you explained how you deduced a=c^m from the GCD condition

Comment: @Buraian It is by letting $a = c^m$ and $1+ a^2 + \ldots a^{n-1} = d^m$. Hence, $a ( 1+ a^2 + \ldots a^{n-1}) = b^m = c^md^m$.

Comment: $c^{mn} > c^m \implies c^{m+mn}-c^m > c^{m+mn}-c^{mn}\implies \frac {c^{mn}-1}{c^m-1} > \frac {c^{mn}}{c^m}$

Comment: @player3236 Right.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Alright, I got your results. Back to the drawing board.